# Get C++ field using regular expressions in emacs lisp

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to get the type and the name of a class field in C++ using elisp and regular expressions

The field is of the type:

```c++
int foo_;
```

(Type: `int`, Name: `foo`)

or

```c++
foo<bar> baz_bar_;
```

(Type: `foo<bar>`, name `baz_bar`)

So far I got these 2 regexes for getting them.

**Type:**

```
.+(?= .*_;)
```

**Name:**

```
\w+(?=_;)
```

The problem is that elisp does not support lookahead.

How could I translate these regexes to elisp-compatible ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than write two regular expressions, how about writing one regular expression and then extracting the sub-matches?  I think this would solve your lookahead issues.  And, if you need the sub-matches at different spots, just do the whole match anyway and only extract the part you need.

So something like (untested):

```
\(.+\) +\(.+\)_;
```

And then to get the type, use `(match-string 1)`, or to get the name, use `(match-string 2)`.

It's worth noting, though, that in general C++ members cannot be matched using regular expressions.  I believe the declarator syntax is pretty complicated and can only really be done using a parser.